a novel feature, tool, or part of a larger machine, method, etc
Let's suppose that a novel invention is for a feature, tool, or part for an already existing larger machine, system, method, etc.
In other words, the novel invention on its own is useless.
In the claims, do I just include the novel elements, even though they would not be of any use without the larger invention?

The is a difference between what is positively claimed and the entirety of the wording of a claim. You can certainly have a claim preamble “a carburetor for use with an internal combustion engine”
Worded this way the carburetor on its own infringes. If the claims says “an engine with a carburetor” then the carburetor on its own does not infringe.
Improved subcomponents are often the claimed subject of invention. The other things to be useful are mentioned inferentially but not positively claimed.


In the claims, do I just include the novel elements, even though they would not be of any use without the larger invention?

Every valid claim must satisfy the utility requirement. One can generally not claim only the novel elements.

In other words, the novel invention on its own is useless.

That's not how utility is gauged. What is the use of a car without petrol? Is the car "useless" on it's own and must be claimed in combination with petrol? (Let's forget electric vehicles for the moment).
The utility requirement is more along the lines of assuming the invention is novel and asking whether there some benefit to humanity with it versus without it. For the utility requirement one must bring in only so much as to establish that the invention is a cohesive whole that accomplishes something. There can still be an environment it requires to work properly.

But the whole doesn’t need to be positively classified claimed. No claim to a novel car is going to recite petrol as a claimed element. Then a car empty of petrol would not infringe.

@GeorgeWhite Yes, that was my point, that that is -not- how utility is gauged. Frequently, as you state in your answer, a subcomponent can be claimed. However even the subcomponent is usually going to have some conventional bits and some novel bits and I think at some point the utility requirement is going to cut off how closely one can get to claiming only the novel bits (which would be ideal).

Other than the issues of abstractness and perpetual motion machines, utility almost never comes up.

@GeorgeWhite Well maybe it doesn't come up often, and applicants frequently have accurate judgement of how to satisfy utility, but I think it's a complex requirement when you think about the bounds of it. For example, when the lightbulb was first invented I think it would not have been possible to claim only the filament, because only the filament can't work in the environment given by the prior art (no vacuumed envelope). But once the lightbulb enters the prior art, an improved filament becomes possible to claim on its own because it fits well into the environment given by the prior art.

Hypothetically- “a filament made of carbonized bamboo in a chamber evacuated of oxygen at least below the level of X atmospheres, the chamber allowing the transmission of light.”
